# JsTree check nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have saved checked nodes in cookies with this code:

```
$.cookie('q_cats', $("#category-tree").jstree("get_checked"), { expires: 7 });
```

I am loading my tree with this code:

```
$('#category-tree').jstree({
            "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox", "search"],
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false
                },
                "data": {
                    "url": "/blogs/get_cats/",
                    "dataType": "json"
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know how can check saved nodes in my tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `state` plugin - it does exactly that - restore state across refreshes / reloads. Just look it up, all you need to do is add a string to your config (plugins section):

```
    $('#category-tree').jstree({
        "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox", "search", "state"],
        "core": {
            "themes": {
                "responsive": false
            },
            "data": {
                "url": "/blogs/get_cats/",
                "dataType": "json"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It was helpful !